# Lipschitz condition!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I was wondering if anyone could think of a proof that the set of all functions in C[a,b] satisfying the same Lipschitz condition is closed, and its closure is the set of all differentiable functions on [a,b] such that the abs value of the derivative f is less than K (the constant of the condition).

In addition, could someone show that M, the union of all the functions satisfying the condition for any K is not closed, though its closure is the whole space C[a,b]?

Thanks in advance for any help! My apologies for the length of the problem.

Comment: What is the metric on $C[a,b]$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. It is the set of all continuos functions defined on the closed interval [a,b], and its metric is p(f,g) = max(abs(f(t)-g(t))) for t between a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the second part. The set of all functions in $C[a,b]$ satisfying a Lipschitz condition (i.e. the union of all the functions satisfying the condition for any $K$) is not closed since by [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) every continuous function (even not Lipschitz) on $[a,b]$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials (which are Lipschitz). For the same reason its closure is $C[a,b]$.

As regards the first part, if a sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and each $f_n$ is $K$-Lipschitz then 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2||f-f_n||+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq 2||f-f_n||+K|x-y|.$$
By taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity we obtain 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|$$
and the set of $K$-Lipschitz is closed. Note that $f(x)=K|x-c|$ with $c=(a+b)/2$ is
$K$-Lipschitz but it is not differentiable at $c\in (a,b)$.

Comment: That solves one of the parts... any idea on the others?

Comment: But wait, what of the first part which says for functions that satisfy the same condition?

Comment: I answered to the second part.

Comment: Yes, I understand, it makes sense. But what of the others?

Comment: See my answer to the first part.

Comment: OK, thanks! I am wrapping my head around it, and you'll have my vote!